# How to extract chroma format for the base or main profile in H.264?

Tags: h.264

chroma_format_idc is present in SPS for the High profile (profile_idc == 100), but not for the Base and Main. How to read chroma format from the Main or Base profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rec.ITU-T H.264 says:

When chroma_format_idc is not present, it shall be inferred to be equal to 1 (4:2:0 chroma format).

So, I guess that is it.